# How can I build a smooth dome?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-mods

I'd like to build a dome roof on a building. There is a trick using command blocks and blocks "riding" minecarts to create a smooth sphere:

It'd like to use something like this to create a half-sphere for my roof.

The trick via command blocks and minecarts works but takes a lot of time. **Is the only option to use command blocks, or is there a mod or filter to do something like this or to automate the minecart trick?**

---

To be clear, it should be like this:

[image]

It should not be like this:

[image]

Comment: Oh! I stand corrected. But that may or may not be useful for you, depending on what you need it for. Do you just need the visual effect, or something more?

Comment: Would an MCEdit filter that creates these spheres be fine, or do you specifically need a mod?

Comment: MCedit doesn't creates smooth spheres.

Comment: All that stuff is important to put into the actual question post, so I've edited it to make what you're asking clearer and more complete.

Comment: My guess is that this can be done using a bunch of armor stands holding blocks.  I have no idea how to get it nice and smooth though.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with [Carpenter's Blocks](http://www.carpentersblocks.com/). It's a mod that adds angled/sloped blocks to minecraft. You will need to use a lot of them to achieve your goal and the sphere will not be entirely spherical - but it will be a lot better than the Vanilla attempt. One warning: Carpenter's Blocks, when used in large numbers cause significant lag, so whether or not you use this method depends on your PC specs and the size of your roof.

Comment: This idea crossed to my mind. The result does not suit me.

Answer (score 0):

You could just run the filter and remove all minecarts with a y-rotation larger than 90°